# Non-linear bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, measurements, bells-inequality, non-locality

Consider the Bell setting, where Alice and Bob get inputs $x,y$ and they perform measurements $\{M^x_a\}_a,\{N^y_b\}_b$ respectively on their shared pure state $\Psi_{AB}$ to obtain outputs $a,b$. Resulting conditional probability distribution is $p(a,b|x,y)$. We have the famous Bell's inequality, and its various alternative formulations, which are upper bounds on the linear combinations of the conditional probabilities $p(a,b|x,y)$.

Lets add a twist to above setting. Suppose while sharing the state $\Psi_{AB}$, an adversary applied an arbitrary unitary $U$ to Bob's part of shared entanglement (this is without loss of generality: applying another unitary on Alice's share would not do any worse). Lets make the situation worse by assuming that adversary even knows which Bell's inequality are the players trying to violate. This operation could severely limit the ability of the state to violate this Bell's inequality, as we discuss below.

We fix a Bell's inequality that is linear combination of conditional probabilities $p(a,b|x,y)$. Then replacing $p(a,b|x,y) \rightarrow \text{Tr}(\Psi_{AB}M^x_a \otimes N^y_b)$, we obtain an expression that is linear in $\Psi_{AB}$. Now, does there exist a clever choice of measurement operators and a shared state $\Psi_{AB}$, such that the state $(I_A\otimes U)\Psi_{AB}(I_A\otimes U^{\dagger})$ will violate the Bell's inequality even under arbitrary $U$? Clearly no because the average $\int_U dU (I_A\otimes U)\Psi_{AB}(I_A\otimes U^{\dagger}) = \frac{I}{d_A}\otimes \Psi_B$ is a product state that cannot violate any Bell's inequality. Since Bell's inequality is linear, there exists a U such that no violation is possible by $U\Psi_{AB} U^{\dagger}$.

But this argument could be circumvented if there were a `non-linear' Bell's inequality; as linearity is crucial to above argument. So my first question is if there are classes of Bell's inequality that are non-linear in conditional probability distributions.

The setting discussed above also appears in the framework of 'misaligned reference frames', where Alice and Bob do not know if their coordinate systems are aligned. Its equivalent to applying an unknown unitary on the shared state of one of the parties. Thus, another question is if non-linear Bell's inequalities (if they are known) are helpful in the setting of unaligned `reference frames'.

Comment: Is $U$ constant (but unknown), or can it be chosen differently in every run?  In the former case, $U$ can be determined by tomography and then compensated for.  Obviously, this can be written as measurement on serveral copies (you might call this "nonlinear").  In the latter case, every *state* is identical to a maximally mixed state, so there is no entanglement, and thus an LHV theory exists.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch - In the former case, how would Alice and Bob independently do tomography on the shared state? For example, the state on Bob's end could be maximally mixed, and the information about the state could be in joint correlation, which may require joint operation by Alice and Bob.

Comment: I think this should work just as with reference frames.  Imagine e.g. that you have a Bell state, but you don't know which one.  Then, you can use local operations to improve the overlap of one of the two states with the Bell state, postselected on a measurement outcome.  (Similar to recurrence protocols for distillation.)  ---  A completely different approach, however, would be to have a large number of measurement settings, corresponding to a sufficiently dense net of $U$'s.  For some of these settings, there will be no LHV model.  In this scenario, you don't even need non-linearity.

Comment: A potentially simple answer to the question above is this: we can test our measurement outcomes against many different Bell's inequalities. Regardless of the unitary 'U', one of these inequalities should be violated.